# Implementing powerUps to change entire game state in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I asked a question recently that sort of involved implementing power-ups; however, I have decided that I want to go about it a different way.

In my game, I have an endless scrolling background and the main character moving to the right while collecting coins.

When the player hits the blue coin, the power-up, I want 1. the character to change to a blue color (I have the frames for this), 2. the background to go blue, and 3. the platform to change blue (have images for this); I would like all these factors to take place for a 20 second period of time.

I planned to do this by having a **Blue** class with a **blue** instance variable (public variable) that I would set to YES and NO accordingly (if a blue coin has been hit) in my other classes (Platform class, Player class). However, it is not efficient and does not work for when I incorporate a timer.

Does anyone have an idea on how to implement the power-up?

This is my code for when the blue coin is hit by the player:

```
    // try remove blue coin
    - (void) tryRemoveBluecoin
    {
    NSMutableArray * currentBluecoinArray = [self getcurrentBluecoinArr];

    if(currentBluecoinArray)
    {
        int playerY = ((CCLayer*)(self.player)).position.y;
        for(int x=0; x<[currentBluecoinArray count];x++)
        {
            CCSprite *bluecoin = [currentBluecoinArray objectAtIndex:x];

            if(abs(bluecoin.position.x+bluecoin.parent.position.x-[Player initX])<50)
            {
                if(abs(bluecoin.position.y+bluecoin.parent.position.y-playerY)<30 && bluecoin.visible && bluecoin.visible)
                {
                    [bluecoin.parent removeChild:bluecoin cleanup:YES];

                    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
                    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"jump.wav" pitch:1 pan:0 gain:1];

                    // SET BLUE VARIABLE TO YES

                    NSLog(@"BEGIN BLUE POWER UP EFFECTS FOR 20 SECONDS");

                }
            }
        }
    }


    [self hitTestOB];
}
```

Thanks for any ideas you have!

Answer (score 0):

Now, it has been some time since I last used Cocos2d, but you are aware that you can actually set color-information to nodes, right? This sounds like a much more sensible way to go down. Design your sprites with this in mind and keep an array with all elements you need to color.

Have a method defining the new color based on your game state, the game state enums can be matched with an NSInteger property on your power-ups for instance.
    ccColor3B color;

```
// _state being an NSInteger ivar
// the different states defined in an enum

switch (_state) {
    case gameStateBlue:
        color = ccc3(0, 0, 255);
        break;
    case gameStateGreen:
        color = ccc3(0, 255, 0);
        break;
    default:
        break;

        // etc.
}
```

send this color information to a method which handles your array of sprites like this:

```
for (CCSprite *sprite in _arrayOfSpritesToChangeColor) {
    sprite.color = color; 
}
```

This will demand planning ahead with your assets, but a lot more flexibility down the line if you want to experiment with different colors and effects. It is a lot less taxing as well as you won't need to swap a bunch of assets to achieve what you want. Now, my Cocos is rather rusty so I might have messed some details up, but the general idea should be sound.

Edit: An alternative to holding reference to the sprites in an array is to have your own sprite subclass and let that subclass have a CCSprite colorSprite property. Then you could loop through the children of your scene and change the sprites that have this property.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately they are not cCSprites, they are animations!

Comment: an animation runs on a sprite, it changes the sprite texture every couple frames

Comment: So I can do the same thing for animations?... Can I change a state in one class and have it be known in another class?

Comment: You will have to do the exact same thing to the sprites making up the animation. As long as the state is a public property it should be straightforward to handle it from any other class.

Comment: Sorry, that should be "the sprite running the animation" (told you I'm rusty),